# Kotlin, manual completo en español?

Tags: android

Me gustaría aprender sobre el nuevo lenguaje por el que apuesta google. Alguien tiene referencias o manuales?

Answer (score 2):

[Aquí](https://www.toptal.com/software/introducci%C3%B3n-a-kotlin-programaci%C3%B3n-de-android-para-seres-humanos/es) te agrego un tutorial en castellano, mientras que [aquí](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) la documentación oficial en inglés